# How many kinds of tags are there in leetcode?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Everyone knows leet code website has many tags like:
array,linked list,...etc

if you want do some practice about array or tree you can just go

https://leetcode.com/tag/array/

https://leetcode.com/tag/tree/

so my question is diretly simple

How many kinds of tags are there in leet code?
Can anyone give me a link that can see all tags in leetcode?

Answer (score 1):

In Leetcode problem page, you can choose the tag for problems. [Leetcode Link](https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/)